# Best Practices for persisting iPod Playlist (MPMediaItemCollection) across sessions

Tags: iphone, mpmediapickercontroller, mpmediaitemcollection

When using in-app audio in the iPhone SDK, it is possible to allow users to select a list from their ipod library and create an in-app local playlist.  If I want to persist this choice, it is easy to serialize the data and write to file, then recover.

Just vanilla like this, however, leads me to think there is going to be something wrong.  For example, what if the user syncs and removes sounds?  I can loop across them all and query the iPod DB at setup time, but with lists that could be 50,000 long, this could take some time.

How are other people doing this and what are some gotchas that I haven't though about?

Comment: Why would anyone want to have such a huge playlist inside an app? Personally (as a user), I prefer the iPod app to manage my playlists, the only thing I want to have access to is the player controls and a visualization of the current playlist.

If I had a playlist e.g. in my GPS Tracking app, it'd probably be very short (>100).

Comment: MPMediaPickerController returns a collection. The # of items in the collection could be the entire library.

Comment: I agree, it most likely is very short.  But I need to cover all bases.  If the user is allowed to pick a preset playlist from the ipod app, it could be the "All Songs" playlist.  and I need to cover this potential choice.

Comment: Precisely why I suggested using the `representativeItem` to build the query. "Theoretically" if the the "All Songs" playlist is chosen, the query will return "All Songs". You only have to handle cases where the query returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just do it lazily,

If a user wants to play a song, you could query the iPod DB, for that song in particular and maybe the whole song "Album" in case the user removed the Album. This would require two requests to the database before playing each song, but you could benchmark if it's fast enough, etc.

You could also put an option somewhere to "`sync`" the application with the `iPod DB`, but given as a choice for the user, giving the user a "warning" that it could take a while, maybe even giving him a time estimation for the size of his particular library.

I think that from a usability/battery saving point of view, this would be better than querying  the whole database each time your application starts, or even in the background.

Answer (score 2):

I initially posted a response around saving the individual MPMediaItems. After some thought and a reread of the documentation for `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate`, I think the approach to use is to save the `representiveItem` property of the `MPMediaItemCollection` and use that to construct an `MPMediaQuery` at runtime.